# adonijs authentication fails with 401 error with corect email and password

Tags: adonis.js

i have created users via factory  using

const Factory = use('Factory')

```
     class UserSeeder {
      async run () {
         await Factory.model('App/Models/User').createMany(5)
        }
     }

  module.exports = UserSeeder
```

and on the factory i have

```
Factory.blueprint('App/Models/User', async (faker) => {
 return {
    first_name:faker.first(),
    last_name:faker.last(),
    username: faker.username(),
    email: faker.email(),
    profile_pic: faker.avatar({fileExtension: 'jpg'}),
    password: await Hash.make("test"),
    status: 1
}
})
```

My auth controller has

```
  class AuthController {
   async login ({ request, auth }) {
      const { email, password } = request.all();
      await auth.attempt(email, password);

    return {message:'Loggedin Successifully',status:true};

}
```

}

Whenever i attempt to login with the correct email and password test am getting an error

```
   field: "password", message: "Invalid user password"
```

What could be wrong as all users are generated by factory with password test

Answer (score 1):

**User** model by default has a **hook** for **Hash** your users **password**,
and you are also hashing the password in the **Factory**, so, the password will never match with your *'test'* password.